# How can I create a callable function from a textarea in Flask?

Tags: python, html, flask

I'm trying to create a Flask application that reads a text function from a textarea in my HTML file and evaluates that to store in an actual function, so I can call it later at any time using my own arguments. For example, if the textarea contained the function:

```
def(a,b):
    return a+b
```

then I want to be able to store that to a variable func within the Flask app, and call func(1,2) and get 3. Is this possible? For what it's worth, my barebones Flask app is included below:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import request
from flask import render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def strategy():
    return render_template("default.html")

@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def strategy_post():
    strategy_raw = request.form['strategy_input']
    return ???

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

with a template of:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body>
    <h1>Input a function below</h1>
    <form action="." method="POST">
        <textarea type="text" name="strategy_input"></textarea>
        <button type="submit" name="submit" value="Send">
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: If your goal is to be able to run python in a browser then you might want to look into http://ipython.org/. As zero has pointed out this is playing with a bon fire.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a little effort you can, but it is really bad idea because it is the straight way for anyone to execute arbitrary code on your server. If you still want do it you can start by looking at [eval](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#eval) and [exev](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#exec) but **think twice before using them** and read at least [exec-in-python](http://lucumr.pocoo.org/2011/2/1/exec-in-python/) before you proceed.

```
>>> foo = eval('lambda x, y: x +y ')
>>> foo(1, 2)
3
```